# HY000 General Error on RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have just set up my Laravel (PHP) project on Amazon with EC2 and RDS. Using MySQL 5.7.

However, I've stumbled upon an error after I log in. I can register a user just fine, but when I log in, I get a general error on a simple query:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1 limit 1)
```

I've tried upping the maximum packet size, but it doesn't help. Also tried running the query directly with MySQL CLI, and it returns the user I created.

Strange thing is that it works just fine locally on my own server (Homestead/Vagrant).

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a problem with HHVM, and not Laravel or RDS/MySQL.

I installed PHP 7 instead, and now it works. Strange...